# How can I send a message using an Ubuntu notification panel?

Tags: ubuntu, notifications

I would like to make a notification of this kind:

[image]

This one is used by `Artha`. Is it `Zenity`? How can I create a notification like that? 
The example is from `Xubuntu 16.04`, of course it might look different on other distros.

Comment: You should take a look [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859585), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187022/how-can-i-send-a-custom-desktop-notification) and [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-use-standard-gnome-notification.html). Maybe one of these links can help you.